# Flutter: Updating database structure

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm using sqlflite with flutter app and I have this methode that initialize the database:

```
initDB() async{
    String dbPath = await getDatabasesPath();
    String path = join(dbPath, 'keemot.db');

    var ourDB = await openDatabase(
      path, 
      version: 1,
      onCreate: _onCreat,
      );
    return ourDB;
  }
```

and this is `_onCreate` method:

```
void _onCreat(Database db, int version) async{
    await db.execute(
      'CREATE TABLE $_table ('
        '$_columnId INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,'
        '$_columnTite TEXT,'
        '$_columnDate TEXT,'
        '$_columnTime TEXT,'
        '$_columnMonth INTEGER,'
        '$_columnDay INTEGER,'
        '$_columnReiteration INTEGER,'
        '$_columnReiterationTarget TEXT,'
        '$_columnNotification INTEGER,'
        '$_columnNotificationTarget TEXT'
      ')'
    );
  }
```

and I wanted to add another table so I did the following:

```
void _onCreat(Database db, int version) async{
    print ('creating ... version => $version');
    await db.execute(
      'CREATE TABLE $_table ('
        '$_columnId INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,'
        '$_columnTite TEXT,'
        '$_columnDate TEXT,'
        '$_columnTime TEXT,'
        '$_columnMonth INTEGER,'
        '$_columnDay INTEGER,'
        '$_columnReiteration INTEGER,'
        '$_columnReiterationTarget TEXT,'
        '$_columnNotification INTEGER,'
        '$_columnNotificationTarget TEXT'
      ');'
      'CREATE TABLE $_settingsTable (' // I added the table to this method like so
        '$_settingsColumnLang VARCHAR (3)'
      ');'
    );
  }
```

But I'm getting this exception:

```
DatabaseException(no such table: settings)
```

I have updated the version in `openDatabase()` method, I thought it will recall the `_onCreate()` method, however still getting the same exception.
What should I do update the database structure ?

Comment: what does `print ('creating ... version => $version');` show? and what do you pass to `openDatabase` method?

Comment: @pskink it shows nothing that's the problem, the `_onCreate()` method is not being called ! and for the `openDatabase` mthod, as mentioned, I just give it the database path, the version and `onCreate` callback.

Comment: @pskink I just give it the database path, the version and onCreate callback

Comment: so give `onUpgrade` too - see the docs: *"[onUpgrade] is called if either of the following conditions are met: ..."*

Comment: should I give it the `_onCreate` mehod too ?

Comment: just see the docs: https://pub.dartlang.org/documentation/sqflite/latest/sqflite/openDatabase.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should call `db.execute` two times for creating two seperate tables.

Also for cases like this I would recommend also providing the `onUpgrade` callback. You could do something like this:

```
var ourDB = await openDatabase(
      path, 
      version: 3,
      onCreate: _onCreat,
      onUpgrade: _onUpgrade 
);
```

And your upgrade method might look like this to drop the old table and call your `onCreate` method again:

```
_onUpgrade(Database db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    await db.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS $_table");
    _onCreat(db, newVersion);
}
```

Comment: sorry still same exception :(

Comment: Have you tried creating two separate tables on separate `db.execute` calls?

Comment: now it worked :) looks like `db.execute` can execute one query at a time. please edit your answer to mark it as accepted.

Comment: @ShababbKarim ```void _onUpgrade(Database db, int oldVersion, int newVersion)async{
    
    await db.execute("""CREATE TABLE ChangePasswordTable(data INTEGER """);
    _onCreate(db, newVersion);
  }```

Comment: @ShababbKarim can to create new table on onUpgrade moethd?

Comment: Did you mean to ask whether I ca create a new table in `onUpgrade` callback? Yes you should be able to create a table on this callback.